# How do I remap axes on my gamepad?

Tags: remapping, input, game-controller, input-device, button-remapping

My gamepad has an issue. It's an old Gembird controller and I don't want to buy a new controller. Its right stick interprets X axis as Y. And vice versa. How can I remap it to solve this issue?

Comment: What are you trying to remap it on?

Comment: You mean swap the axis? This needs to be done in the driver settings (if it exists).